# Laravel date validation in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to not allow the user to save data on a specific date. Now my code will lead to user can't save data even if the user selected a specific date. How do I allow the user to save data when the date is not on the specific date?

Code :

```
static::save(function($model)
    {
        //User can't save data between this date
        $from = date('2018-01-01');
        $to = date('2018-11-19');

        //Disable save function between specific
        if (User::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get()&&
           (!property_exists($model, 'always_writable') || !$model->always_writable)) {
            $model->setErrors(trans('validation.read_only'));
            return false;
        }
        return $model->validate();
    });
```

Comment: how do you then save the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check against the count of the query:

```
//if count is greater than 0

static::save(function($model)
    {
        //User can't save data between this date
        $from = date('2018-01-01');
        $to = date('2018-11-19');

        //Disable save function between specific
        if (count(User::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get()) > 0 &&
           (!property_exists($model, 'always_writable') || !$model->always_writable)) {
            $model->setErrors(trans('validation.read_only'));
            return false;
        }
        return $model->validate();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

quick maffs with unix timestamps.

```
 static::save(function($model)
        {
            //User can't save data between this date
            $from = strtotime('2018-01-01');
            $to = strtotime('2018-11-19');

            //Disable save function between specific
            if ( !(property_exists($model, 'always_writable') 
                && $model->always_writable) 
                && (time() >= $form && time() <=$to)){
                $model->setErrors(trans('validation.read_only'));
                return false;
            }
            return $model->validate();
        });
```

edit: added the `always_writable` conditions.
edit2: made your always_writable checks actually do something sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you meant to achieve with the query:

```
User::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get()
```

This basically gets all users in the system with a date column between $from and $to. Presumably this will always be true. Shouldn't that be:

```
Auth::user()->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->count()
```

Which means: is the current logged in user's date column between $from and $to?

Alternative:

```
$userDate = Auth::user()->date;
if (($userDate >= $from && $userDate <= $to) && ... ) {
  ...
}
```